# How to know whether didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called because of user launching the app or the system

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is using Voice Over IP "voip" mode in **Required background modes**, thus whenever the app crashes, or system terminates it while in background, then it's auto-run sporadically by the system.

My question is, how to know whether *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* is called because of user launching the app or the system. Because I need to dismiss different events if app was autorun by the system.

NB. For either cases, launchOptions dictionary returns *null*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState`. When running in background it will return `UIApplicationStateBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the contents of the `launchOptions` dictionary.

Someone has actually documented all the possible options [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys)

Comment: For either cases, launchOptions dictionary returns null